# Sum Matches to a Google Sheets Query across an Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a table with two rows - a person's name and points. I'm looking to create a third column that uses an Arrayformula to match the name in column A and sum up the points for that person across all of column B. 
A and B are static (with new entries added to the bottom) so I'm looking for the formula to use in column C.

| Name | Points | Person's Total Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 1. | 1.25 |
| Ellen Dee | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Jerry Lewis | 2 | 3 |
| John Smith | 0.25 | 1.25 |
| Jerry Lewis | 1 | 3 |

Here is a sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a1aQf4h4Qf1P_5YDldCxpHkaYtIQrFQjLQ3LR2LiJaE/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried this formula in C2 but it isn't working properly:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A="",,QUERY($A$2:$B,"SELECT SUM(B) WHERE A = '"&$A$2:$A&"'")))`
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(A2:B, "select A,sum(B) group by A"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",, sumif(A2:B,A2:A,B2:B)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).